# Caret shifted down on second line if using CSS line-height – Is there a workaround?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, cursor-position

Using the `line-height` property in a `contenteditable` div causes the caret to be shifted down once you move it to the second line. This is more apparent with some custom web-fonts but also happens with standard fonts like Arial. Is there a workaround for this behaviour?

**This shows the caret on the first line**

[image: Normal caret on the first line]
**Caret on the second line shifted down**

[image: Shifted caret on the second line]

*A demo of the behaviour can be found:* http://jsfiddle.net/sGgVR/

**Edit:** The browser used for testing Safari 6.0.1 and Chrome 22.0.1229.94

Comment: I cannot duplicate this behavior. I see the carat going above and below the characters whether I'm on line 1 or line 2. And removing `line-height` CSS does not affect this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any elegant solution for this. When `line-height` is less than a `font-size`, lines overlap and cursor's top part is cut-off by top text-box.

Maybe `:first-line` pseudo-element will help somehow, though, give it a try. But I couldn't get a good use of it here.

Another kinky way is to break multi-line texts onto several different elements using JS. Each with contentEditable of course. And then creating new elements on line-breaks, merging on backspace or delete. But this solution seems like *way* overcomplicated.